# Python: add object, then change properties

Tags: python

I use a python script to place a whole bunch of plane objects in a 3d grid (in layer 2 but that's not important), like in this example, where I just copied the primitive_plane_add syntax from what appears in the "info" pane when I add a plane object.

```
import bpy
layer2=(False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
for i in range(-5,5):
    for j in range(-5,5):
        for k in range(-5,5):
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=0.2, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=layer2)
```

I found [this post](https://code.blender.org/2011/05/scripting-%E2%80%93-change-settings-the-fast-way/) on blender.org that explains how to change a property for all objects, but what I want to do is change the property of the given object right after creating it. So, the above code would look like this:

```
import bpy
layer2=(False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
for i in range(-5,5):
    for j in range(-5,5):
        for k in range(-5,5):
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=0.2, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=layer2)
            #So we've just added one more plane.
            #While we're here, select the just-created object
            #Then, change the object's color, transparency, tell it to be shadeless, etc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using add primitive operators, the object that is created is marked as the active object. You can access the active object using `obj = bpy.context.active_object`.